# why are my colours changing when i use imagetruecolortopalette()?

Tags: php, colors, imagemagick, gd, closest

I have an image 4x4 pixels, each pixel has the exact color that i want e.g #439902 etc,

I grab my image convert it to a palette using gd's `imagetruecolortopalette()` function, then i try to find the closest color in my image to another predefined color using `imagecolorclosest()` function, the problem is that it brings back a different color altogether, one thats not in my 4x4 image, the color is close to one of my colors but i need it exact.

I think the problem is that when i use to `imagetruecolortopalette()` function all the colors in my 4x4 image slightly change,

Is there a way round this problem.?

As an example...

if i Search for ( 66,100,39 )  my closest Match is: (76,90,56).

well 76,90,56 has changed because the colour was (78,98,43) in my original image.
I know its not far out but i need it to stay the same

Comment: colorclosest works as if the colors were points in 3d space - what is closest straight-line distance between two color "points" is not necessarily the closest 'visual' match. You might want to try imagecolorclosestwb() which works more perceptually than mathematically.

Comment: I understand about the color space and the math behind it. It's not a problem that it picks the closest color using the straight-line distant. As long as it gets a colour in my image.. and it does, The problem is that the colors from my original saved image are different from the outputed image, my image is a PNG and is outputted as PNG, i have compared both images and they are different colored pixels. I think it is a compression problem but i have tried to save it as PNG and JPG and although there is slightly different results in color they still do not match the original PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving as a jpg it might be a compression problem; try saving as a png as it does not compress and has more colours than jpg.

Some code lifted from the IM forum:

```
exec("convert square.png[1x1+0+0] -format " .
     "\"%[fx:floor(255*u.r)],%[fx:floor(255*u.g)],%[fx:floor(255*u.b)]\" " .
     "info: 2>&1",$result);
      print_r($result);
```

I think am going the wrong way here as this will identify the colour and that is not what you want?

Comment: I think it is a compression problem but i have tried to save it as PNG and JPG and although there is slightly different results in color they still do not match the original PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

but php has already this function:

[imagecolorexact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorexact.php)

Comment: i might not have the exact color in my image so i just want the closest color, and closestcolor works well its just that the colors are changing slightly when saved

Comment: [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) have compression option and filters; did u tried the default way (pass nothing) or played with these?